# drupal - schedule a script to run at specific time

Tags: drupal

Totally new to drupal.

I'm building a module that lets the user specifies the time to run an external script through a form. I imagine I'd need to play with `hook_cron` ? but from what I understand, it only runs when the cron is set up to run. So how do I tell Drupal to run the job at this time and that time,etc, everytime the user submits the form?

For example, the form would look like:

```
Start: 10:00 am 
End: 11:00 am

<Submit>
```

So when the user submits, Drupal will first run the script (defined in my module) at 10 am then again at 11 am.

What module/hook do I need?

Comment: cron is all about running at intervals. So you can't set a date/time to run. instead, an interval. In your hook_cron(), you can load the data and check if the current time has passed it. The more frequent the cron runs, more accurate your script running would be. Check how phpjobscheduler (not Drupal - a stand alone project) does that.

Comment: thank you. I will just increase the frequency for the cron

Answer (score 0):

Configure your Drupal site to run its cron every 1 minute. Then implement a hook_cron in your module and inside this function loop through the different jobs added through the form and run them at the given time points entered through the form.